# Use oid as primary key

Tags: sql, postgresql

Is it possible to use oid data type as primary key?

```
CREATE TABLE "Test"
(
  id oid NOT NULL DEFAULT nextval('"Test_id_seq"'::regclass),
  "some" text,
  CONSTRAINT "Test_pkey" PRIMARY KEY (id)
)
```

I want to use unsigned int data type.

to **DrColossos**

> Furthermore, you can't use foreign key constraints on OIDs (at least this is what google tells me)

```
CREATE TABLE "Test"
(
  id oid NOT NULL,
  val text NOT NULL,
  CONSTRAINT "Test_pkey" PRIMARY KEY (id)
);

CREATE TABLE "Test2"
(
  id integer NOT NULL DEFAULT nextval('"Test2_Id_seq"'::regclass),
  "TestId" oid NOT NULL,
  CONSTRAINT "Test2_pkey" PRIMARY KEY (id),
  CONSTRAINT "Test2_TestId_fkey" FOREIGN KEY ("TestId")
      REFERENCES "Test" (id) MATCH SIMPLE
      ON UPDATE CASCADE ON DELETE RESTRICT
);

INSERT INTO "Test"(id, val) VALUES (1, 'one');
INSERT INTO "Test"(id, val) VALUES (2, 'two');

select * from "Test";

insert into "Test2" ("TestId") values (1);
insert into "Test2" ("TestId") values (2);
insert into "Test2" ("TestId") values (4);

ERROR:  insert or update on table "Test2" violates foreign key constraint "Test2_TestId_fkey"
DETAIL:  Key (TestId)=(4) is not present in table "Test".

select * from "Test2";
```

Comment: If you dump the data and restore it, using OIDs can result in conflicts since they are autogenerated by the DB, so you always need to dump with `-o` to make sure that OIDs are exported as well. Furthermore, you can't use foreign key constraints on OIDs (at least this is what google tells me). So you should REALLY(!) know what you are doing if you use OIDs in your application.

Comment: Maybe, the most common I've found is the ability to not use it in references. Not sure how it does in indexes or similar. I would advise you against such a design choice.

Comment: Thank you for comment. I am just considering the possibility of using oid

Comment: Ask yourself why you'd want to use an OID, and not just an integer or bigint.

Comment: @nos _I want to use unsigned int data type._ And postgresql does not give unsigned data types.

Comment: @vaychick: why do you need an unsigned int? If you are concerned about the maximum value simply use a biginteger.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name But in some cases 4 bytes enough if you use all range and not half of range. Using bigint instead unsigned int is wasteful IMHO.

Answer (score 1):

Just trying it would have told you whether it's possible.  The answer is yes.  (It's unusual, but offhand I can't see a reason why it would cause problems.)